# If I know an element and it's inverse, can I learn the modulus?

Tags: group-theory

If I know an element $x$ in a group, and it's inverse $x^{-1}$, can I guess the modulo, or with a probability?

Comment: The question makes sense in the group $\Bbb Z_n^*$ for unknown $n$. Hint: what do you know about the ordinary product $x^{-1}\,x$ ?

Comment: @fgrieu The product $x^{-1}x= nk+1$ for an integer $k$, with the bits of $n$ increase and for larger $x$, it will be more complex? But even more complex, it will always get the modulo in polynomial time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments above, you have that $x \cdot x^{-1} = 1 \mod n $. 
Another way to say that is $k \times n=(x \cdot x^{-1}) -1$

So no, you can't always find the exact value $n$ from $x$ and $x^{-1}$.

Take $x=12 \ $ and $x^{-1}=17$. You have $x \cdot x^{-1} = 204$. 
So $n$ is a divisor of $204-1=203$, meaning, $ n \in \{29,203\}$ (other divisors are smaller than $\max(x,x^{-1})$ so they can't be $n$)

The only cases where you can find $n$ is when the only divisor of $kn$ greater than $x$ and $x^{-1}$ is $kn$ itself. In this case, $n=kn=(x \cdot x^{-1}) -1 $

Comment: You are right, so can I think it is a difficult factoring problem as the $n$ is large enough?

Comment: Can you please give some details about your _problem_ ? What I understand is, given $x$ and $x^{-1}$, can an adversary retrieve $p$ and $q$ such that $pq=n$ ? Is it correct ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean that while $x^{-1}x$ is large, so the $kn$ is large enough, so it can be seen as a hard problem: from $kn$ to find $k$ and $n$?

Comment: What would be the use of the $x$, $x^{-1}$ and $k$ values ? The public key would be $(x,x^{-1})$ and the secret one $(k,n)$ ?  Your question need a bit more of contextualization. Where did you get this idea from ?

Comment: Note: you can add: if we know more than one pair we can find more about the $n$.

Comment: @BaptisteCottier When I construct my scheme, I meet this problem, I would like to  do a security analysis. Thank you guys!

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you guys! If we know more than one pair, we certainly to find the modulo. But with only one pair, we may get some different $n$, but not sure what is the right ont.

Comment: @w.qi Not _certainly_. Take $(x_1,x_1^{-1})=(18,21)$ and $(x_2,x_2^{-1})=(14,27)$. You have $x_1\cdot x_1^{-1}=378$, so from this, $n \in \{29,377\}$. Then, you have $x_2 \cdot x_2^{-1}=378$. Here again, you can deduce that $n \in \{29,377\}$. So from this pair of values you only know that $n \in \{29,377\}$, not the exact modulo.

Comment: @BaptisteCottier Haha, thanks, I make a mistake, only when the $x_1^{-1}x_1$ and $x_2^{-1}x_2$ be different, can we get the modulo.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't get an example but I don't see why you could not have $x_2 \cdot x_2^{-1} = \lambda \cdot  x_1 \cdot x_1^{-1}$. $x_2 \cdot x_2^{-1}$ will be different of $ x_1 \cdot x_1^{-1}$, but you can't deduce the modulo.

Comment: @Bissi: Hint: the modulo divides both $x_1^{-1}\,x_1-1$ and $x_2^{-1}\,x_2-1$, which both are computable. That allows to find to modulo, or an usually small multiple thereof.

Comment: @w.qi It is almost certainly not a hard problem: Hard problems are only hard for hard instances of the problem, and unless you specifically choose $k, n$ to be large primes, then factoring $kn$ will not be difficult.